# How do I set a reminder that doesn't appear on my calendar as an appointment?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Reminders really aren't appointments. Is there a way in Outlook to set a reminder that doesn't appear as an appointment on my calendar? If not, is there a way to prevent certain appropriately tagged appointments from appearing in the calendar view?

The issue I'm trying to solve is that my actual appointments and meetings are camouflaged among a bunch of recurring reminders that clutter up my calendar. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in this scenario but it always helps to give as much detail as possible, when talking about Microsoft Office, always give the version as well, 2010, 2013, 2016, 365...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use Outlook tasks then. Create a task and enable the reminder for it. This task will not appear in your calendar and you still get the reminder functionality.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Reminders are in fact the same as appointments as they represent a time that you should get to do a specified task.

The fact that you have so much stuff in your calendar gives me the impression that there could indeed be some improvement in your operations.  Big companies normally organize these situations with tools more specific to what is being done, often using specialized or custom solutions.

Since both types of your calendar task are apparently different categories of schedules that clog up your Outlook calendar so much, you might want to use another calendar tool, or set them up in different accounts to separate the two.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only thing you can do is to create an appointment and in the "Show As" section, change it from "Busy" to "Free".  That way it won't throw flags with the "Scheduling Assistant" but you can still set a reminder.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a secondary calendar (I use one for planning my Tasks).